# coq 8.11.0 incompatible with ocaml 4.10?

Tags: ocaml, coq, opam

I am installing coq with opam [as per these instructions](https://coq.inria.fr/opam-using.html) and have gotten the error message

```
`No solution for coq: The following dependencies couldn't be met:
          - coq → ocaml < 4.10
              base of this switch (use '--unlock-base' to force)
```

I proceeded to switch to ocaml 4.05.0 with the following command

```
opam switch create with-coq 4.05.0
```

and could install Coq successfully, but I'd much rather use the updated version of ocaml. Is this an actual incompatibility between Coq and oCaml, or am I doing something wrong?

For added context, I am now using opam 2.0.6, ocaml version 4.05.0, and Coq version 8.11.0.  My operating system is macOS. Prior, the only difference was that I tried to use ocaml 4.10.0.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like Ocaml 4.10 made some breaking changes. See [this issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/10726).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the tip of the v8.11 branch or wait for 8.11.1 which should be out shortly.

You don't need to go back to 4.05.0 tho, 4.09 will work fine, tho 4.07.1+flambda is the one I recommend, see https://coq.discourse.group/t/install-notes-on-coq-and-ocaml-versions-configuration/713